# How to filter json based on a query dynamically generated?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I want to filter a json object using js for an angular project.
The Json structure would be like this:

```
{
 "docs": [
{
  "Firstname": "",
  "Lastname": "",
  "Birthdate": "",
  "city": "",
  "country": ""
},
{
  "Firstname": "",
  "Lastname": "",
  "Birthdate": "",
  "city": "",
  "country": ""
}
]
}
```

the query builder is similar to [angular-query-builder](http://mfauveau.github.io/angular-query-builder/)

A Sample query that could be generated using the query builder would be something like as follows:

```
(Firstname = tom OR (Firstname = jerry AND Lastname = jack))
```

based on this query a Js function should filter the json object and console the resulting json .

Have seen custom functions for filtering, but don't know how to create a dynamic filtering function based on the query being generated.

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: Maybe try reading the documentation? https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-query-builder

Comment: Do you want to filter the `"docs"` array? If so, then you can simply use the JavaScript's Array filter function. But perhaps you also need to show us what you have tried and what errors/problems you have encountered.

Comment: @Marv, I was just looking for ideas that could be used for building a custom filter function based on the query string generated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom filter (if you don't want to use a query builder) to filter out all values based on FirstName and LastName

```js
function MyCtrl($scope){
    $scope.people = {
 "docs": [
{
  "Firstname": "Tom",
  "Lastname": "Larry",
  "Birthdate": "",
  "city": "",
  "country": ""
},
{
  "Firstname": "jerry",
  "Lastname": "jack",
  "Birthdate": "",
  "city": "",
  "country": ""
},
{
  "Firstname": "Tom",
  "Lastname": "Thomas",
  "Birthdate": "",
  "city": "",
  "country": ""
},
{
  "Firstname": "jerry",
  "Lastname": "gaer",
  "Birthdate": "",
  "city": "",
  "country": ""
}
]
}
    $scope.myFilter = function(item){
        if((item.Firstname == "Tom")||(item.Firstname == "jerry"&&item.Lastname == "jack")){
            return true;
        }
    };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
       <ul>
           <li ng-repeat="person in people.docs | filter:myFilter">
{{person.Firstname}} {{person.Lastname}}
           </li>
       </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: For a pre-determined querry. this is enough. But what about a query dynamically generated as in anular-querry builder? How will be filtering dynamically possible?

Comment: I don'r know anular query builder but from your question the query (Firstname = tom OR (Firstname = jerry AND Lastname = jack)) feels like predetermined to me

Comment: actually that was a sample querry,which could be generated using the querry builder.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an object, which reflects the relation of the conditions and their grouping.

> Example for the given condition
>
> ```
> (Firstname = tom OR (Firstname = jerry AND Lastname = jack))
> ```
>
> Take an object for the predicates
>
> ```
> {
>     type: 'group',
>     operator: 'OR', 
>     conditions: [
>         {
>             type: 'expression',
>             key: 'Firstname',
>             value: 'tom',
>             comparison: '='
>         },
>         {
>             type: 'group',
>             operator: 'AND',
>             conditions: [
>                 {
>                     type: 'expression',
>                     key: 'Firstname',
>                     value: 'jerry',
>                     comparison: '='
>                 },
>                 {
>                     type: 'expression',
>                     key: 'Firstname',
>                     value: 'jack',
>                     comparison: 'jack'
>                 },
>             ]
>         }
>     ]
> }
> ```